# Most unanswered tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Just saw https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers and seeing 18% unanswered of ~400k seemed like a lot. I'm guessing there's a tag with more unanswered answers, right?

Which is the tag with the most unanswered questions (not percentage)?

Comment: on the other hand, what's the tag with the most answer/question ratio? I only ask this because I'm not sure how to execute this on data.se

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bill presented a query for this, and results as of the end of 2012 in his question ["Help us clean up the Android tag."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100529/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag) The query you want can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1320/unanswered-questions-by-tag), which I believe is the original creation of Jon Seigel and Greg Hewgill.

Comment: Spoiler: highest unanswered count is still [android], with [facebook] as the highest unanswered percentage.

Comment: "[facebook] as the highest unanswered percentage". I'm shocked. Shocked I say